# Capacitor Hard ware back button closing the app in release build

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am handling the back button by adding a listener in the _app.tsx of my react project like so

```
useEffect(() => {
        CapacitorApp.addListener("backButton", () => {
            if (router.pathname === "/") {
                CapacitorApp.exitApp();
            } else {
                router.back();
            }
        });

        return () => {
            CapacitorApp.removeAllListeners();
        };
    }, [router]);
```

and it is working as expected in the dev build without any issues.

But in the release build the back button is closing the app

My capacitor package versions

```
"@capacitor/android": "^3.5.1",
"@capacitor/app": "^1.1.1",
"@capacitor/cli": "^3.5.1",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.5.1",
```

I have tried removing the whole android folder and readding it

and also issue only happening with aab(android app bundle) if I build a normal apk the back button logic is working perfectly and not exiting the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known issue you just need to copy the following proguard rules into your app's proguard rules

```
# Rules for Capacitor v3 plugins and annotations
 -keep @com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin public class * {
     @com.getcapacitor.annotation.PermissionCallback <methods>;
     @com.getcapacitor.annotation.ActivityCallback <methods>;
     @com.getcapacitor.annotation.Permission <methods>;
     @com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod public <methods>;
 }

# Rules for Capacitor v2 plugins and annotations
# These are deprecated but can still be used with Capacitor for now
-keep @com.getcapacitor.NativePlugin public class * {
  @com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod public <methods>;
}

# Rules for Cordova plugins
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.* {
  public <methods>;
  public <fields>;
}
```

You can see the issue and workaround at https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5606#issuecomment-1122461215

Comment: Thanks, your contribution looks great! Do you have a link to an official resource citing this as a known issue? If so, that might make an excellent addition. Welcome to SO! Looking forward to your future posts.

Comment: @SherylHohman I have edited the answer and added the link to issue on github

Answer (score 0):

I think you are subscribing wrong. It should be 'ionBackButton'. Like it says in the documentation ([here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button#basic-usage)):

```
  ev.detail.register(10, () => {
    console.log('Handler was called!');
  });
});
```

Comment: No I am using capacitor only and not ionic the documentation to the listener I am implementing is [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#addlistenerbackbutton) and also it is working in dev build it stops working only in the aab release build it is working even in the release apk only stops working in aab build